# How do I bypass the "one answer per 3 minutes" rule?

Tags: discussion, answers, rate-limiting

I am one of the developers of Kubernetes.  We have an on-call rotation answering questions here, but we get rate-limited in our answers.

How can I, the owner of the product, answer more questions without this silly rule?

Comment: The rate limit exists for a reason . . .

Comment: I believe the IP-based rate limit only exists until you hit 125 reputation: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259942/19679 , so the members of your group won't be limited as a whole once individual members are above that threshold. It's there to reduce the damage spammers can cause before they are caught.

Comment: Per the [FAQ on rate limits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide), you remove the limit by gaining a bit of reputation.

Comment: Please read the [help]. Many of your answers should be in fact comments.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251755/839601

Comment: I have just flagged 5 of your posts as "NAA". Please, please, read the rules. They ain't silly.

Answer (score 21):

Tim, I reviewed some of the recent answers you posted. While we love when developers get involved in providing technical support for their communities, the purpose of a question on Stack Overflow is (hopefully) to take that opportunity to create a canonical resource for *everyone* who may come across that same issue. We are a bit like Wikipedia in that respect.

I don't mean to criticize someone's need or desire to provide free technical support to those who need it, but your answers really do look somewhat terse and rushed. I'm sure that is not your intention, but when someone comes to Stack Overflow looking for help, the entire purpose of having this site is to go beyond helping just that one person… hopefully to create something lasting for those who come after.

I hope you will take this in the helpful and grateful spirit it is intended — but the rate limit really *does* serve a purpose. If you are bumping up against it on a regular basis, it might be useful to take a step back and consider if your answers really do represent the best possible resource your service has to offer… for those who come after.

Take care.